# Can I set a padding to the hamburger icon on Android 4.4 from Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[Image shows versions 7.1 and 4.4,the top two images are the default ones, to the bottom two we added some customization ,see description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCXCN.png)

What I want to achieve is that on Android 4.4 the hamburger button to have a space in front so that it doesn't start right from the edge of the action bar/screen(much like on 7.1,see screenshot).Can I add a padding to the hamburger button?I am using Xamarin.Forms with Xamarin Studio.

The problem seems to be worse when we add a custom view to the action bar,it sets the hamburger button more to the left I think,and doesn't entirely fit in the screen and somehow "cuts it off".

This is the relevant part of how we add the custom view to the action bar.We do this with a custom NavigationRenderer and we do the UI from code.

```
   actionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
  LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);
            linearLayout.SetGravity(GravityFlags.CenterVertical);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

            switch (activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi)
            {
                case DisplayMetricsDensity.Xhigh:
                    textViewParameters.RightMargin = (int)(48 * activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
                    break;
                case DisplayMetricsDensity.Xxhigh:
                    textViewParameters.RightMargin = (int)(64 * activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
                    break;
                default:
                    textViewParameters.RightMargin = (int)(48 * activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
                    break;
            }

            TextView modelTitle = new TextView(activity);
            modelTitle.Text = view;
            modelTitle.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            modelTitle.TextSize = 17f;
            Typeface type = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "abc.ttf");
            modelTitle.SetTypeface(type, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
            modelTitle.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
            linearLayout.AddView(modelTitle, textViewParameters);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams actionbarParams =
                        new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

        activity.ActionBar.SetCustomView(linearLayout, actionbarParams);
```

I also tried to change the hamburger icon to a drawable(I added a space before the same hamburger icon,and it would do the job),but once I navigate back to the page using the back button (from the same action bar),my icon is replaced by the default hamburger button again.

I would appreciate any help.Thank you!

Edit:

```
public class MainView : MasterDetailPage
    {
            public MainView(parameter){
            ......

             sideMenu = new CustomContentPage();//my custom Content Page with listview items
            base.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Split;
            sideMenu.Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(50, 0, 0), 0, 0);
            Master = sideMenu;
            .......
            }
    ...
    }

    public class App : Application
    {
        private MainView lcMenu = null;
        .....
        if (lcMenu == null)
                {
                    MustSet = true;
                    lcMenu = new MainView(parameter);
                    lcMenu.RequestPage += LcMenu_RequestPage;
                }
        ....
        MainPage = lcMenu;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is the relevant part of how we add the custom view to the action bar.We do this with a custom NavigationRenderer and we do the UI from code.

Seems that you're creating your own master detail instead of using the [MasterDetailPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/) of XF? Not sure, but I think you went the wrong direction, for setting the padding of hamburger button we need to customize `MasterDetailPage`.

> I also tried to change the hamburger icon to a drawable(I added a space before the same hamburger icon,and it would do the job),but once I navigate back to the page using the back button (from the same action bar),my icon is replaced by the default hamburger button again.

As I said, we can customize the `MasterDetailPage`, in the renderer, we can find the `ImageButton` for hamburger button, for example:

```
public class MyMasterDetailRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
{

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as ImageButton;

            var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable;
            if (drawerArrow == null)
                continue;
            //set drawable
            imageButton.SetImageDrawable(Forms.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.hamburger));
            //set padding
            imageButton.SetPadding(80, 30, 80, 30);
            //set background
            imageButton.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Grace.Thanks for your answer.i think this code works for toolbar only.we use an action bar.Tried to get it working but I couldn't

Comment: @TamasNorbert, not exactly, that's why I said looks like that you're customizing your own master detail page instead of directly using the `MasterDetailPage` of XF. By official `MasterDetailPage`, it uses `Toolbar`. If you insist to customize by yourself, you will need to post the layout code and so on.

Comment: .It is not about insisting to customize the MasterDetailPage ourselves,but the project is in its latest phase,and would be too much overhead work to change it and make sure we
don't introduce unwanted bugs. I posted some additional info,please see my Edit to the original post!. Note: I also accidentally Edited your post and added my code there,sorry!